# Postgresql - show usage of INTEGER, BIGINT

Tags: linux, postgresql, database-administration

I've a big PG database.
There are INTEGER and BIGINT fields. Integer has mas max value 2 147 483 647 and bigint 9 223 372 036 854 775 807.

How can I find fields where usage (max. value is very near) is big (about 80-90%) to change field type? Are there any tools for that?

I can use a custom script and make many inquiries to db, but maybe there is a Linux tools for that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question only makes sense if the columns you are talking about are filled from a sequence.

If I understood you right, you could use this query to figure out to what percentage the available numbers are exhausted:

```
SELECT relname AS sequence_name,
       coalesce(nextval(s.oid) /
                CASE a.atttypid
                   WHEN 'smallint'::regtype THEN 32767::numeric
                   WHEN 'integer'::regtype THEN 2147483647::numeric
                   WHEN 'bigint'::regtype THEN 9223372036854775807::numeric
                END, 0) * 100 AS percent_used
FROM pg_class AS s
   JOIN pg_depend AS d ON d.objid = s.oid
   JOIN pg_attribute a ON d.refobjid = a.attrelid
                          AND d.refobjsubid = a.attnum
WHERE s.relkind = 'S'
  AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
  AND d.classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

This assumes that there is a relationship between the column and the sequence, which is established for `serial` and `bigserial` columns as well as identity columns.

This bit of advice probably comes too late, but you should always use `bigint` for generated keys, because then you never run danger of running out of numbers.

Comment: Fine, but now I get `There is a column named "oid" in table "s", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.` PG 9.6

Comment: I have replaced the query with a version that should also work with older PostgreSQL versions.

Answer (score 0):

That will be better, I've changed nextval to currval - it doesn't change a counter of current sequence.

```
SELECT relname AS sequence_name,
       coalesce(currval(s.oid) /
                CASE a.atttypid
                   WHEN 'integer'::regtype THEN 2147483647::numeric
                   WHEN 'bigint'::regtype THEN 9223372036854775807::numeric
                   WHEN 'real'::regtype THEN 6::numeric
                   WHEN 'double precision'::regtype THEN 15::numeric
                END, 0) * 100 AS percent_used
FROM pg_class AS s
   JOIN pg_depend AS d ON d.objid = s.oid
   JOIN pg_attribute a ON d.refobjid = a.attrelid
                          AND d.refobjsubid = a.attnum
WHERE s.relkind = 'S'
  AND d.refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
  AND d.classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: "*I've changed nextval to currval*" - but it will fail if you have not called `nextval()` in that session.

Comment: Is is safe to bump sequence number without adding data? We'll have an omitted seq no in table.

Comment: Define "safe". As sequence generated numbers are expected to have gaps, there is nothing wrong with losing one number.